# Why Catalog search index failing?

Tags: magento2.4.2

I did upgrade my Magento version 2.3.4 to v2.4.2
Then activate ElasticSarch and upgrade the composer

then the site working for me. Admin and Frontend have appeared without any error.

but showing a warning on my AdminDashboard
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

When I run **bin/magento indexer:reindex**
it showing

Catalog Search index process unknown error:
{"error":"MapperParsingException[No handler for type [text] declared on field [_search]]","status":400}

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I did try this comments but still the error is there

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/ vendor/

Help me to resolve this issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSiUl.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ6GF.png

Comment: What elastic version you have configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your ElasticServer is up and running. You can use the following CLI commands to test the availability and the outcome:

curl localhost:9200

Pleas keep in mind that the ElasticSuite ^2.6 supports ElasticSearch 6.x so use it. A lot of things got fixed enhanced on that version. Also ElasticSuite ^2.6 is not compatible with ElasticSearch 2.x.

Installing ElasticSearch 6.x
For a detailed instruction ""tutorial"" please refer to the official Smile_Elasticsuite documentary to get everything correct
https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/ServerConfig-5.x#installing-elasticsearch
After you installed and configured ElasticSearch and ElasticSuite do the following steps:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Clear magento Cache

Comment: one of the main issues is  ElasticSearch did not work properly because of the Java version issue. And also Re-index issue was there, it is due to the elasticSearch version issue. v6 to v5 will work fine

Comment: You must install and configure Elasticsearch before upgrading to Magento 2.4.x.
Refer to the System Requirements for specific version information: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html
Magento does not support Elasticsearch 2.x, 5.x, and 6.x.